# get the size of an array in an array in perl

Tags: perl

@myArray is an array with one element. The element is an array with 20 elements.

```
@myArray->
        [0]-> 
             [0]
              .
              .
              .
              [19]
```

How do I get to the size (20) of the array inside the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereference the array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr = [5..24];
print scalar @{ $arr[0] }, "\n";
```

Output:

```
20
```